# Azure functions deployment slots traffic adjuster not showing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

I have two deployment slots available but the traffic manager that is supposed to the in the right most column isn't showing up. What could be the reason for this?
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UquM.png)

What I'm referring to: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBDaV.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to scale out the app service plan or try to open the same in a new browser/in Incognito mode.